# STContains Always False

Tags: sql-server, spatial-query

I've uploaded a shapefile to SQL Server using ogr2ogr. This shapefile represents St. Tammany Parish.

Now I'm trying to check if a given coordinate falls within the parish and if not, then check if it is *n* meters away from the parish. To do this, I'm using geography::STContains for the first requirement and geography::STDistance for the second.

The issue is that STContains is always returning false. What is particularly frustrating is that if I select the geography field and the point, then look at the spatial results in SSMS, it appears to me that STContains should be returning true.

This is the query that I'm running:

```sql
DECLARE @0 INT; SET @0 = 30.480252;
DECLARE @1 INT; SET @1 = -90.112577;
SELECT TOP 1
    Jurisdiction.GeographicArea,
    geography::Point(@0, @1, 4326) AS Coordinate,
    (geography::Point(@0, @1, 4326)).STContains(Jurisdiction.GeographicArea.MakeValid()) AS PointContainsShape -- returns 0,
    Jurisdiction.GeographicArea.MakeValid().STContains(geography::Point(@0, @1, 4326)) AS ShapeContainsPoint -- returns 0,
    Jurisdiction.GeographicArea.MakeValid().STDistance(geography::Point(@0, @1, 4326)) AS DistanceFromPointToShape -- returns 16580.3696843463
FROM
    Jurisdiction
```

And these are images of the spatial results; notice that 30.480252, -90.112577 falls almost in the middle of the GeographicArea:

**GeographicArea**
[image: geography spatial results]

**Coordinate**
[image: coordinate spatial results]

At this point I'm a bit lost. Why would the geography methods return a false value when I can clearly see that the point is in the geography?

Comment: What does `Jurisdiction.GeographicArea.STIsValid()` return?

Comment: @Charlieface - that is returning false too

Comment: Then the values aren't actually valid in the first place (perhaps overlaps or something), is there any reason you are storing them like that? I suggest you look at the spatial view results of `Jurisdiction.GeographicArea.MakeValid()` and see what's going on

Comment: @Charlieface - this would make sense, I'm relying on the client to provide me with the shape file and I'm relying on ogr2ogr to convert the shapefile. So anyone of those two could give me bad results.

Comment: @Charlieface - actually, the answer is much simpler. I've erroneously declared the variables as ints instead of floats so it is rounding the point to 30/90.

Comment: The code you have may just be a demonstration, but I'd suggest calculating the point once and using it wherever you need it instead of repeating the same thing several times. Incidentally, if you do it like `declare @p geography = geography::Point(30.480252, -90.112577, 4326);`, you avoid the "accidentally cast my coordinates as int" issue.